# Multiple case statement for grouping values 0-9, 10.20

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have this first case statement below which I need to merge with the case statement below this for grouping values together like this:

```
days range   | Activity_submit
-------------------------------------
   0-9       |        11
  10-19      |        14
  20-29      |         3
```

---

```
 SELECT 
    events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay' AS "Days_before_stay",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ((events_raw.properties ->> 'event_type') LIKE 
    'fs_mystay_activity_submit') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Request Count"
    FROM events_raw
```

second case statement to merge with first

```
select events_raw.properties ->> 'days_before_stay' AS "Days_before_stay" [days range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case  
    when days between 0 and 9 then ' 0- 9'
    when days between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    else '20-99' end as range
  from events_raw) 
group by 1
```

Comment: mysql <> postgresql, please don't tag products not in use. It's a case *expression* not *statement*

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your table structure, but here is example where you can see group by expression.

```
SELECT 
    (id/10)*10 toOrder, -- addition field to sort by
    (id/10)*10 || ' - ' || ((id)/10+1)*10 AS range, 
    count(*) myCount
FROM report
GROUP BY 
    (id/10)*10,
    (id/10)*10 || ' - ' || ((id)/10+1)*10, -- group by expression
ORDER BY toOrder;
```

Instead if id you can use any integer field.